# Trying to get a single record involving MAX(Date) and GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a query in which I start with an item number and a customer and I have to determine the last selling price.

The tables involved are

SOP30200 = Sales Header
SOP30300 = Sales Detail lines

Given the following code and results:

CODE:

```
SELECT 
    SOP30200.CUSTNMBR,
    MAX(SOP30200.DOCDATE),
    SOP30300.ITEMNMBR,
    SOP30300.UNITPRCE
FROM 
        SOP30200 
        INNER JOIN
        SOP30300 ON 
            SOP30300.SOPNUMBE = SOP30200.SOPNUMBE AND 
            SOP30300.SOPTYPE = SOP30200.SOPTYPE
WHERE
    SOP30200.SOPTYPE = 3 AND
    SOP30200.CUSTNMBR = 'FAKECUST' AND
    SOP30300.ITEMNMBR = 'FAKEITEM'
GROUP BY
    SOP30200.CUSTNMBR,
    SOP30300.ITEMNMBR,
    SOP30300.UNITPRCE
```

RESULTS:

```
CUSTNMBR    (No column name)              ITEMNMBR                          UNITPRCE
FAKECUST  2013-07-12 00:00:00.000         FAKEITEM                          16.80000
FAKECUST  2014-02-14 00:00:00.000         FAKEITEM                          17.14000
```

I am getting 2 records because the query is grouped by UNITPRCE and we have sold this item to this customer at two different prices. That much I know, however, I want to see those four fields but only one record that has the latest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `order by MAX(SOP30200.DOCDATE) DESC` and change `Select` to `Select Top 1`.

Comment: I'm going to recommend this isn't deleted, but I'd highly suggest adding more information and context. You don't mention WHY this works, or what is going on.